# Adding wikis categories on the fly when creating new Wiki article

Tags: taxonomy, term-store, enterprise-wiki

On the following link http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2011/09/creating-knowledge-centre-with_07.html they mentioned how i can build a term store containing categories, and when users create wikis they can select which category it follows, but this raised the following questions:-

1. They mentioned that users can create new categories –that is not in the term store hirarchy- when they create new wikis, so where will the new category be located inside the term store hierarchy.
2. Is there a way in SharePoint to prevent users from adding categories, so that only site collection admins can do so?
3. can users add more than one category for each wiki article?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you set up your managed metadata, since both ways are possible. Using enterprise keywords enables a tagging system where users can select existing keywords or create new ones. It's similar to tagging a question here, where you select existing tags or, if you have 300 reps, create new ones if they are needed.

Keywords have no hierarchy, so I guess the article referred to managed terms, where only user with the right permission can edit managed terms.

If you want to allow the user to set up multiple values is entirely up to you, since it's a field setting called "allow multiple values", which you control.

> ## Managed terms, enterprise keywords, and the term store
>
> Terms can be divided into two types:
>
> - Managed terms, which are usually pre-defined, can only be created by users with the appropriate permissions, and are often organized into a hierarchy.
> - Enterprise keywords, which are simply words or phrases that have been added to SharePoint Server 2010 items. All enterprise keywords are part of a single, non-hierarchical term set called the keyword set.

Reference and more to read: [Managed metadata overview (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

---

## Edit

To prevent users from adding their own categories follow these steps:

1. In your wiki site, go to Site Actions > View all site content
2. Click on the Pages-library
3. Click the library tab in the ribbon
4. In the Settings pane, click the Library Settings
5. In the Columns section find and click the Wiki Categories column
6. At the very bottom - find the Allow fill-in option and select No.
7. Click OK to save your changes

[image: allow fill in screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply. But on this link http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2011/09/creating-knowledge-centre-with_07.html , they define a managed term hierarchy , then users can add categories -Enterprise keywords- when adding new wiki articles if the keyword is not in the hierarchy . so it seems that we can use Managed terms and Enterprise keywords to refer to each other, is it right?

Comment: can any one advice?

Comment: @JohnPeter Sorry for the late reply. I've updated my answer to show how you disallow users from adding their own categories. Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for your great answer, but let say users are allow to insert categories on the fly, where will these categories be in the term store hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

If the Allow Fill-in option is set to yes, terms the user types are added to the root of the wiki categories term set.

Although this is not ideal, an administrator can then move the terms to a more appropriate location.

Comment: Is there any way for users to insert a new term set somewhere within the hierarchy? Say for example my term set has 3 levels, and the user wishes to create a new keyword within this level